# Cannot run Flutter app on Android virtual device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-virtual-device

I created simple Flutter app, installed Nexus virtual device, but when I tried to start an app, I get the error shown below.

> Android emulator version 31.3.9.0 (build_id 8700579) (CL:N/A) emulator: INFO: Found systemPath E:\AndroidStudioSettings\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ emulator: INFO: Found systemPath E:\AndroidStudioSettings\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR |
> Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.

I have the latest Android studio, Android virtual device, Flutter and Dart plugins.

Comment: Can you share the output of 'flutter doctor'

Comment: @batuhand here is the output:
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just go to terminal and run the command:

```
flutter config --android-sdk pathToYourSDK
```

If you are not sure where is your Android SDK located, do the following:
Go to `Tools --> SDK Manager` and you will see Android SDK location.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download another virtual device, select the new device and try to run on that device.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked with me is making a new virtual device, but an easier solution was to **Wipe User Data** and it runs just fine.

.

I don't know why it happens, though; it's quite annoying!

Answer (score 0):

In Mac,

> `flutter config --android-sdk /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk`

Worked for me. Just restart your Opened Development Environment i.e. Android Studio etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the SDK in the project structure, if using android studio