# Why can't open emulator?

Tags: flutter

```
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)
INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\ 
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): SupportPixelFold 
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD 
ERROR | is an experimental feature. 
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. 
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled 
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. 
INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.156.46
```

this shows when I'm trying to connect with the emulator and how to solve this?

Comment: Just look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297335/cannot-run-flutter-app-on-android-virtual-device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run Flutter app on Android virtual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297335/cannot-run-flutter-app-on-android-virtual-device)

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the other emulator as it appears you are attempting to run it twice.

```
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD 
ERROR | is an experimental feature. 
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to launch a device with screen size 800x1280 on 5" (with depsity 300 dpi). So after some emulator restarts I saw this line in the logs:

`qemu: Bad LCD density: 300. Available densities are: 120, 140, 160, 180, 213, 240, 280, 320, 340, 360, 400, 420, 440, 480, 560, 640`

Also I had the line before that one.

`Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): SupportPixelFold`

So I had to play with screen sizes.